# ASPxGridView Find control (Checkbox) and Check if it is checked or not

Tags: asp.net, gridview, devexpress, findcontrol

I have a checkbox (you can see below) nested in detailed grid. How can I find it on updating click and check if checked or not? I'm using DevExpress GridView

```
<dxwgv:GridViewDataCheckColumn Visible="false" VisibleIndex="14">
<EditFormSettings Visible="True" />
        <EditItemTemplate>
         <dxe:ASPxCheckBox ID="ASPxCheckBox1" Text="" runat="server">                                                     </dxe:ASPxCheckBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>                                                                                  </dxwgv:GridViewDataCheckColumn>
```

Comment: Why would you use the EditItemTemplate and place a simple CheckBox in it? That's what DevExpress out-of-the box does without specifying the EditItemTemplate. It also provides two-way databinding in that case.

Comment: I just started to use Devexpress controls. Can you show me please an example how can I accomplish the same idea but in better way?

Answer (score 2):

```
Protected Sub grid_RowInserting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataInsertingEventArgs) Handles grdProyectos.RowInserting
        Dim grid As ASPxGridView = (TryCast(sender, ASPxGridView))
        Dim chk As CheckBox= grid.FindEditRowCellTemplateControl(grid.Columns("name_colum"), "nameCheckBox")
        Dim marcada as Boolean = chk.Checked
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in Selection feature of the ASPxGridView. It has events and methods to find the selected rows. Take a look at this sample:

http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/Selection/Selection.aspx