# Getting the Checkbox Ids in DexExpress AspxGridView

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have an DevExpress aspxGridView with GridViewCommandColumn checkbox as the first column to select rows. After user selects rows, I need to get the rows where the checkbox is checked in a button click. Please help to do that. I am new to DevExpress controls.

Comment: What datasource do you use? And have a look here if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602978/aspxgridview-find-control-checkbox-and-check-if-it-is-checked-or-not

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the approach described in the following Support Center ticket:

http://www.devexpress.com/issue=Q303022

If it just necessary to retrieve a particular selected rows’ key / non-key values, use the [ASPxGridView.GetSelectedFieldValues](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_GetSelectedFieldValuestopic) method.